# How to combine to Segoe Icons in WPF Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icons

i would like to create a button, that shows a combination of two Segoe Icons, i.e. House (E80F) and Add (E80F) as shown in the picture. How would I approach this in C# / WPF / xaml?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can't just put two TextBlocks on top of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grid with fixed size and equal width and height. Make one icon fill the grid. other icon 30% of width and height and align it to right and bottom.